# "to SearchPage" call from the "then" block

Tags: java, grails, groovy, spock, geb

Why is the below Geb test failing with the below error. Can't I call `to SearchPage` in the then block?

```
Condition not satisfied:

to SearchPage
|
null

    at test.LogoutSpec.Verify that the logout takes the user to login page(LogoutSpec.groovy:35)



def "Verify that the logout takes the user to login page"()
    {
        given: "I successfully logged in to the application"
        to LoginPage
        loginForm.with
        {
            loginClientCode = "testingclient"
            loginSystemCode = "testingsystem"
            loginUserId = "abc"
            loginPassword = "password1"
        }
        loginButton.click()

        at SearchPage
        section == "Search Applications"

        when: "I click Log Out link from user panel"
        userPanel.logOutLink.click()

        then: "I am redirected to the LoginPage"
        at LoginPage

        and: "My session is invalidated"
        //TODO how to verify this
        to SearchPage
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `then` block is for assertions. If that helps, you can add another when-then and put `to SearchPage` in the `when` block.